# How to minimize try..catch() which is used in Laravel functions of the same Controller

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, try-catch, laravel-8

I have Controller like this:

```
class TronController extends Controller
{
    public $tron;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $this->solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
        $this->eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
    }

    public function totalUsers()
    {
        try {
            $tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
            $TransactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($tron);

        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
        $address = ADDRESS;
        $addressH = $tron->toHex($address);
        $contract = CONTRACT;
        $contractH = $tron->toHex($contract);
        ...
    }

    public function totalTickets()
    {
        try {
            $tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
            $TransactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($tron);

        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

So as you can see, at the two functions of this Controller, I have repeated the same `try..catch()` for setting up `$trone` variable.

Now in order to refactor this,  I added `try..catch()` to the `__construct()` function:

```
       public function __construct(){
            $this->fullNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
            $this->solidityNode = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');
            $this->eventServer = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Provider\HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io');

            try {
               $tron = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);
               $TransactionBuilder = new \IEXBase\TronAPI\TransactionBuilder($tron);

           } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
               exit($e->getMessage());
           }
        }
```

But this will return an **ErrorException**:

`Undefined variable: tron`

Which is referring to this line:

`$addressH = $tron->toHex($address);`

So the question is, how can I write less code by minimizing the `try..catch()` and use that in the functions without getting error ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create just one method containing try/catch block it from and returning the tron  and call them from your controllers action method.

Comment: @biesior Please can you provide me an example, I'm just getting numerous errors!

Comment: or add property `$tron` into your class and access it in constructor and actions via `$this->tron`, when you using it in controller like `$tron` it is accesible only in the method's scope. Edit: As i can see you have already it - `public $tron;` so just change `$tron = new ...` to `$this->tron = new... ` in controler, and in actions read it with `$this->tron`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an approach that may help help you in refactoring your code to have less duplicate codes.

### Laravel pipeline

You can create a class and add your logic in a method in that class, then send your data through that class and do your repetitive logic in there.

For example, for making `$tron` create a class `MakeTron` in anywhere you prefer

```
namespace App\Http\Controller;

class MakeTron
{
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            return new \IEXBase\TronAPI\Tron($this->fullNode, $this->solidityNode, $this->eventServer);

        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And in your code just use pipeline

```
$tron = app(\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::class)
    ->through([\App\Http\Controller\MakeTron::class])
    ->thenReturn();
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the reason for creating dedicated class, while OP can do it via property generated in constructor, what he almost have, just need to access it properly?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I just created a Controller `MakeTron` and also added the pipeline after the `public function totalUsers()`  starts, but I get `Target class [\App\Http\Controller\MakeTron] does not exist.`

Comment: @KKKKKK I've updated the answer. `->through([\App\Http\Controller\MakeTron::class])`

Comment: @biesior, yes, you're right. I'm just trying to give a solution using decorator approach.

Comment: @biesior there is even no need to exit code, because laravel have built-in error handler and it can be customized to reflect proper action on different exceptions or just using `report()` instead of php `exit()` function.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Then where to add `$TransactionBuilder` variable ?

Comment: @KKKKKK You can add another method like `BuildTransaction` in your class and handle it using `$tron = app(\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::class)
->through([\App\Http\Controller\MakeTron::class])
->via('BuildTransaction')
->thenReturn()`